# What is the physical meaning of resistance and power ratings of a loudspeaker?

Tags: power-supply, impedance, resistance, sound, speakers

[image]

What exactly does it mean when it is specified that internal impedance (or resistance?) of a loudspeaker is 16 \$\Omega\$? Is that ohmic resistance of the copper of its internal winding? Or is it absolute value of its impedance value? If it is an impedance value; a loudspeaker can play sounds with a wide variety of frequencies, how can they specify a general impedance for a loudspeaker?

And also for power rating, what is the physical meaning of it? Is it the maximum power of sound (the energy transferred to the molecules in the air as vibration in one second) that a loudspeaker can give out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specified impedance is the sort-of average over the relevant frequency range for the speaker. Googling for "speaker impedance" shows [a few graphs](http://archive.is/wD1Sm). The impedance consists of an ohmic part and a much more complicated part. The ohmic part is (hence) much lower than the rated impedance.

The power rating is the total amount of electrical power you are allowed to feed the speaker without destroying it (but there might be other limits, like the amount of power in certain frequency bands). It is certainly not the energy in the sound waves produced: a speaker has a very low efficiency, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loudspeaker#Efficiency_vs._sensitivity) cites 0.5 .. 20%.

Comment: Is there any consistency at all to such ratings, except when specific frequencies are mentioned (e.g. "8ohms at 1kHz")?  It might be helpful to have ratings that indicated, things like, "Cannot be damaged by any input below 10 watts, nor any input 10Hz or higher below 25 watts", or "Output THD below 1% for any input signal comprising 25Hz-20KHz with total power 50 watts or less provided total power at any single frequency does not exceed 25 watts".  I've generally not seen any consistent format for such specs, though.  My personal thought is that advertised "rated power" should be tied to THD.

Comment: I am no expert, but I guess you need to consult the real datasheet for such details. The impedance and power rating is only a very rough summary.